# Testing code generated by a Swift Package

Tags: swift, xcode, graphql, code-generation

I am developing a Swift Package that also includes a code generator. Is there a way to test the generated code using XCT? The important part is that tests use the generated code.

I thought I could add a test target and only build it after the code generation step. I can't find a way to add a build step to Swift package, though. Is this possible?

Another "solution" that I've considered is creating a workspace that references a project with generated code and the package itself. Then, I would create two targets and add a code generation build step to the test project. The problem with this idea is that we don't get test coverage and I am not sure how to add Swift Package to a workspace. Is there any tutorial on this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can't you write unit tests for the code generator instead, if the code generator is ok then the generated code should be ok?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson right, that's one possible way to do it. I was thinking more in terms of having an end-to-end test suite.